# How to add a specific line to every C++ source file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want visual studio 2013 to add particular set of lines (in my case `#pragma warning (disable : 4996)`) when i add new file in source file.

In simple words `#pragma warning (disable : 4996)` **should be already written/inserted** in every source file that I create or add.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template file of your code file, for example for C# class go to this path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

and add your line wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you !! :) I wanted to make changes for c++  class and i went on this path  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VC\Code but i wasn't able to find 1033 folder there .   Please correct me if i'm doing something wrong as I'm new to visual studio.

Comment: I couldn't find much either, the only thing that I've found was in this path:

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VC\XAML\1033\BlankPage**

, I suggest you edit your question or ask a new one and say exactly what language and what template in that language you are using.

Comment: I'm using c and i get a blank page when i add a new source file .I hope this will help .